# How to define general interface for Object with constans?

Tags: typescript, typedef, type-definition

In project I have a few Objects with string constants. For example:

```
export const Elements: Constants {
    DESCRIPTION: "DescriptionAutoField2",
    FORMULA_CALC: "FormulaCalcAutoField1",
    CHART_CODE: "ChartCodeAutoField1",
    CHART_CODE_DESCRIPTION: "ChartDescriptionAutoField1",
};

export const ChartAttr: Constants = {
    CHART: "Chart",
    CHART_DESCRIPTION: "ChartDescr",
};

export const SliceLink: Constants = {
    SLICE_CODE: "SliceCode",
    SLICE_DESC: "SliceDesc",
    SLICE_CALC: "SliceCalc",
};
```

I defined the interface like this but in this case imposible to check Object kyes during compilation.

```
 export interface Constants {
       [key: string]: string;
 }
```

My question is: how to define general interface "Constants" and have strict compilation based on defined Object properties? Is it posible to avoid "enum"?

Comment: use enum or const enum

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no single concrete type like `Constants` that will match all of `Elements`, `ChartAttr`, and `SliceLink`, while *at the same time* remembering the exact keys and values of each.  Instead, you can represent a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html) type which matches your constraint and use a helper function to ensure that the values conform to it while outputting a strongly typed value that remembers individual key/value types:

```
// helper function
const asConstants = <S extends string, T extends Record<keyof T, S>>(
    c: T
): { readonly [K in keyof T]: T[K] } => c;
```

I assumed you wanted the constant properties to be marked as `readonly` and that the type of each value should be a [string literal](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#string-literal-types) and not just `string`.

Now you define your constants via the function instead of an annotation:

```
export const Elements = asConstants({
    DESCRIPTION: "DescriptionAutoField2",
    FORMULA_CALC: "FormulaCalcAutoField1",
    CHART_CODE: "ChartCodeAutoField1",
    CHART_CODE_DESCRIPTION: "ChartDescriptionAutoField1",
});

export const ChartAttr = asConstants({
    CHART: "Chart",
    CHART_DESCRIPTION: "ChartDescr",
});

export const SliceLink = asConstants({
    SLICE_CODE: "SliceCode",
    SLICE_DESC: "SliceDesc",
    SLICE_CALC: "SliceCalc",
});
```

If you inspect the types of `Elements`, `ChartAttr`, and `SliceLink` with your IDE's IntelliSense, you see:

```
/*
const Elements: {
    readonly DESCRIPTION: "DescriptionAutoField2";
    readonly FORMULA_CALC: "FormulaCalcAutoField1";
    readonly CHART_CODE: "ChartCodeAutoField1";
    readonly CHART_CODE_DESCRIPTION: "ChartDescriptionAutoField1";
}

const ChartAttr: {
    readonly CHART: "Chart";
    readonly CHART_DESCRIPTION: "ChartDescr";
}

const SliceLink: {
    readonly SLICE_CODE: "SliceCode";
    readonly SLICE_DESC: "SliceDesc";
    readonly SLICE_CALC: "SliceCalc";
}
*/
```

And if you try to pass a bad value to `asConstants()` you get an error:

```
asConstants({
    NOT_A_STRING: 1, // error! number not a string        
})
```

Okay, hope that helps. Good luck!

[Link to code](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play//#code/MYewdgzgLgBAhhAwuacxQjAvDAPAZRgFMAPKIsAE02gCcBLMAcwBoYAVYsi6mAJSKhalXAGsiATxAAzDm3wA+BQAoAsACgYWmMABcHDQEp9Abxi0icSuAA2EmAG0A0jEYxxU2ewC6+9s+8YAF9sBR0Abg0NUgAHEFpYUEhYAFEbIgBbCgxseCQUKDQMZRMNbRgAERT8RD4ASQAFdjqAeQA5fQAiCqIIYAYYqHpwAEEAVygQADF6IhtKACZOljLtKZa+AFkAVQAZEYB9RBHdxC6p+IyxmzhEOBtgccmZucoARmXVrUQACRG+dhHFpVLqIAAWcASyEoRCe01m8w+K002l+-0BiGBKQOVRq9SarQ6ME64MhUB6fQGQ1GE3hryRGiChki6gA9AAqDRJaAwNKZbIQUxfcyWaxgOyVaq1RrNdpdCn9eiDYZgOEveZLFnlCxWWz2dZbPaHY6nc6Xa63e6PWnq96dLXaHViiVogFAkHE0lQkAwtUIu0OrROvUwV0YrE4qX42VEkkQhIKqkqv30+2MjTs1lRdSxeKJAqh+NQEZQKC0XIIZDJIoQErCsOgoufFHfP5u3HSglyz1FxPNpksjlcgte4ul2hClsi3Xi+wNntktNT4Oz0NtwEd6OExtkvssoIZrPqaIkOIJHQF-A2ejAIi7RiiCv5avoWulKf4XZ1RDYzEezpXjeRDQkQzblJ+37Yh2XSAbeCpgdoEE-kcJxnMSsHAVa-bMhoQ7qNysAYfeYCiJO2qiiGSG-liMHXreIFLuRM4SlRkY1LRQHwYG07OvYrEmmhAF0ZhDxLge6iZtmlYFDWdZTm0LSAoc+DsPUbQAOL6G8bCsqyxC0LQ8QAIQwGAYwZAARkQ5ZgCAsBwDAdCMEw5TlIyhgaEAA)